# First occurrence of a house built on a graveyard?

Tags: first-appearance, trope

I was doing some research on an unrelated topic, and the movie [*Poltergeist*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_(1982_film)) (1982 version) appeared to be the first occurrence of a residence being haunted because it was built over a cemetery.

I am aware of a few other films post dating it, and some jokes about "Well, it's not built on an Indian burial ground", but is Poltergeist the first instance of a location being haunted because it is built over a previously unknown burial site?

Please note: I am specifically asking about houses or other residences being built over a hidden/unknown graveyard. Not something like Phantasm or House by the Cemetery where the building is in a known cemetery.

Edit. For clarification, I would include any sort of living quarters, such as a hotel or similar. A place intended to be for human habitation, so not a warehouse that has a bunk bed in the back.

Comment: *"is Poltergeist the first instance"* Er, no, [another little film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shining_(film)) with that concept came out 2 years prior. ;) But wasn't it a literary trope even before that?

Comment: @Walt Literary trope, yes. It was used in amityville horror (1977) for sure as a literary, I don't think the movie mentioned it. (Or at least I don't remember it in the movie).

Comment: Wait, so does *The Shining* not count because they *knew* they built it on a burial ground?

Comment: I would say yes, simply because it's kind of a "reap what you sow" sort of deal. Poltergeist was some happy family with no idea. Kind of like where you get what you deserve when you live in a former mortuary.

Comment: The Amityville movie *did* mention it, though, making it an earlier example (1979).

Comment: How do you feel about Hotels? The Hotel featured in The Shinning was build on top of an Native America Burial Ground. That film's date is 1980. I would think there would be even earlier examples...I will think on it a while. Sorry, I see someone else has also mentioned that.

Answer (score 7):

The [origin](https://news.avclub.com/read-this-digging-up-the-origins-of-the-indian-burial-1798285639) of this trope apparently began with [*The Amityville Horror*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amityville_Horror) novel.  However, there seems to be no mention of an Indian burial site in the movie.

[*The Shining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shining_(film)) from 1980 seems to be the first film to mention a site built on an Indian burial ground.

> The site is supposed to be located on an Indian burial ground, and I
>   believe they actually had to repel a few Indian attacks as they were
>   building it.

[*The House by the cemetery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_by_the_Cemetery) from 1981 is a lesser known horror film that was made a year prior to *Poltergeist*.  This film depicts a house that sits on a gravesite.  There's actually a tomb in the basement.

Comment: Doesn't need to be an Indian burial ground, any will do. I added the line as it is its own trope, basically.

Comment: @JohnP Well, I was trying to add both an indian burial ground and just an actual gravesite/cemetery.  I had never heard of _The House by the Cemetery_ before!  It actually sounds really interesting :)